# How to restrict Samsung S3 and similer devices to ddownload and install my application in android

Tags: java, android, manifest, tablet, screen-resolution

What i need to do is to restrict all handset not able to download this application. This is just for all tablets. I added this code to my manifest as per the guidelines [Link](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens-distribution.html). here is the code :

```
<supports-screens
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="false"
    android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="600"
    android:smallScreens="false"
    android:xlargeScreens="true" />
```

But still i am able to install this application in my Samsung s3 and similer devices. How can i assure that it would not download and install in any handset only in tablets. Please reply if anybody have idea in the reference

Comment: Tablets usually donot have sim functionality, try to look into TelephonyManager Api

Comment: The difference between phones, tablets, phablets, and other devices is becoming more and more blurred these days. Many phones have a higher screen resolution than tablets. Why do you want to allow only tablets ?

Answer (score 0):

[Supports-screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens-distribution.html#FilteringTabletApps) or [user-feature](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html#sw-features) are just an indication for Google Play to allow or not a user to download your app but will not block you to install your app through the command line or android studio.